# Getting word count with Grep

Tags: shell, unix, grep, uniq

I have been using

```
grep -o string file | wc -l
```

to obtain word counts, but I have a file of the format

```
help
help
help
how
how
luke
mark
```

And I was wondering if there was a command that would return: 3,2,1,1

Instead of running the previous command multiple times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
sort input.txt | uniq -c
```

which will output

```
   3 help
   2 how
   1 luke
   1 mark
```

from which you could continue processing the output. If you already know that the same entries are in a continuous block of lines you could of course skip the `sort` and use `uniq` directly, which will also preserve the order.

Comment: Now lets say the output ended up being: 5,8,3,12,7. Is there a way to sort it in descending order?

Answer (score 0):

single process awk way

```
awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(x in a)print x" : "a[x]}' file

kent$  echo "help
help
help
how
how
luke
mark"|awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(x in a)print x" : "a[x]}'
luke : 1
help : 3
how : 2
mark : 1
```